# RewriteCond fetch array values from Query_String and redirect as url path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using htaccess how to convert

> https://www.example.com/plex/?param1[]=apple

To

> https://www.example.com/plex/apple/

Below condition throws an error:

> .htaccess: RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression
>   'param1[]=(.*)'

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param1[]=(.*) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/ [QSD,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `[` and `]` as those are special regex meta characters:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)param1\[\]=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/%1 [QSD,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Tried the following:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)param1\[\]=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^path1/ /path1/%1/ [QSD,L,R=301]

It redirects to www.example.com/path1/Array/ . Btw, stackoverflow is hiding the escape characters in the above Condition for [ ]

Comment: What is original URL and what is your expected behavior?

Comment: 1. Orginal url: https://www.example.com/path1/?param[]=apple - Expected redirect: https://www.example.com/path1/apple/
2. Orginal url: https://www.example.com/path1/path2/?param[]=apple - Expected redirect: https://www.example.com/path1/path2/apple/

Comment: Btw, my mistake - I was trying with %5B%5D instead of [ ]

Comment: How do I allow other parameters to continue to be redirected as is... example: param1[]=apple&price=1,10 should become /apple/?price=1,10

Comment: @anbhava here is the question for retaining other parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133237/rewritecond-fetch-array-parameters-from-query-string-and-convert-into-path-while