# RewriteCond fetch array parameters from Query_String and convert into path while retaining the remaining parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How to allow few parameters to continue to be redirected while one paramter which is an array to be converted into a string in the url path

> example: param1[]=apple&price=1,10 should become /apple/?price=1,10

```
Orginal url: example.com/path1/?param1[]=apple&param2=1,100
Expected redirection: example.com/path1/apple/?param2=1,100

Orginal url: example.com/path1/path2/?param[]=apple&param2=1,100&param3=yes
Expected redirect: example.com/path1/path2/apple/?param2=1,100&param3=yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule that will handle `param1[]=` query parameter anywhere:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?param1\[\]=([^&]*)(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1/%2?%1%3 [R=301,NE,L]
```